# label text on Controller Unity VR

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, steam

I want to add label of text on my controller of HTC VIVE in Unity like [that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMJDI.png) but after many research on internet, I don't find how to do.

Someone can help me ?

thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Steps to create text on controller :-

1.Drag camera rig prefab in your scene.

2.Attached Player script of stream VR plugin on camera rig.

3.Attached Hand script on both controllers.

4.Create a empty game object as a child of each controller ,set their local positions at (0,0,0) .Now add script ControllerButtonhints on both. Drag controllerbuttonhints material on controller material ,set any flash color,drag prefab controllertexthint from stream VR prefabs.

5.In Hand scripts drag other hand i.e. in left controller drag right controller and in right vice versa , set starting hand type is Any for both controller.,drag controller prefab as blank controller prefab in stream VR .

6. In player script ,drag camera rig to tracking origin transform, add camera eye as hmd transforms ,add both controllers in hands array,leave other things none and untick allowtoggleto2d also.

7.Last step is comment line no 279 -288 as we don't required for our current purpose.

Although my English is not so good but may be it help you.

Thanks,